# tomcat 10: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual Error

Tags: java, java-16, tomcat10

I need to upgrade to using apache tomcat 10, Java 16.

jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api and jersey-cdi1x was imported.
But it's alway show error.

```
ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual
at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiServerComponentProvider.initialize(CdiServerComponentProvider.java:34)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ComponentProviderConfigurator.lambda$null$0(ComponentProviderConfigurator.java:55)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$15$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:540)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ComponentProviderConfigurator.lambda$init$1(ComponentProviderConfigurator.java:56)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.createApplication(ApplicationConfigurator.java:98)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.init(ApplicationConfigurator.java:72)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:290)
at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4203)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:290)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:987)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4851)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5155)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:880)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.enterprise.context.spi.Contextual
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1401)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1224)
... 54 more

[image: Error]

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the **scope** of the `jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api` artifact to `provided`, therefore it is not deployed with Tomcat. Tomcat is not a full Jakarta EE 9 server, so it doesn't provide a copy of the CDI API.

Modify your dependencies to look:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.SP1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @FixBug: actually `jersey-cdi2-se` does not work in a servlet environment. I corrected the dependencies in the answer.

Comment: Great!!!! Thanks for your help. when I using jersey-cdi2-se, SessionScoped alway error. Change to jersey-cdi1x-servlet -> Fixed.